# How to Disable a warning across projects in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, warnings, suppress-warnings

I know this sounds bad but how can I disable/suppress a specific warning for all the projects in a solution. All of my projects are VC++ projects. Is it possible? If yes, how can this be done?

Environment is Visual Studio 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it can be done using the IDE itself. The way we do it is to have a global include file Configure.h that contains stuff that has to be set/defined/declared for every source file. This include file also disables some warnings using pragmas.

Regards,

Sebastiaan

Comment: Yes, this was exactly the idea I had in mind but I thought may be someone can enlighten me to a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this at a global level in VS2005.  The best way is to suppress individually in every project in the solution.